# Date format in Java not parsing

Tags: java, android, date

I want to know how can I format date in java.
I have the following code,

```
String endDate = textEndDate.getText().toString();
                Log.d(TAG, "Date endDate");

                Log.d("ADebugTag", "Value: " + textEndDate.getText());
                // = "03/26/2012 11:49:00 AM";
                SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
              //  Date convertedDate = new Date();
                try {
                    actualendDate = dateFormat.parse(endDate);
                    Log.d("ADebugTag", "Value actualendate: " + actualendDate.toString());
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

logcat as follows.

```
05-31 18:54:24.651: D/NewBet(17235): Date endDate
05-31 18:54:24.651: D/ADebugTag(17235): Value: 2015-07-30
05-31 18:54:24.661: D/ADebugTag(17235): Value actualendate: Thu Jan 05 00:00:00 GMT+08:00 36
05-31 18:54:24.661: D/NewBet(17235): onCreate() Restoring previous state
05-31 18:54:24.681: D/libc(17235): [NET] getaddrinfo+,hn 13(0x6170692e706172),sn(),family 0,flags 4
05-31 18:54:24.681: D/libc(17235): [NET] getaddrinfo-,err=8
05-31 18:54:24.681: D/libc(17235): [NET] getaddrinfo+,hn 13(0x6170692e706172),sn(),family 0,flags 1024
05-31 18:54:24.681: D/libc(17235): [NET] getaddrinfo-, 1
05-31 18:54:24.681: D/libc(17235): [NET] getaddrinfo_proxy+
05-31 18:54:24.731: D/libc(17235): [NET] getaddrinfo_proxy-, success
05-31 18:54:24.731: I/global(17235): call createSocket() return a new socket.
05-31 18:54:24.731: D/libc(17235): [NET] getaddrinfo+,hn 13(0x35342e3136342e),sn(),family 0,flags 4
05-31 18:54:24.731: D/libc(17235): [NET] getaddrinfo-, SUCCESS
05-31 18:54:26.113: D/libc(17235): [NET] getaddrinfo+,hn 13(0x6170692e706172),sn(),family 0,flags 4
05-31 18:54:26.113: D/libc(17235): [NET] getaddrinfo-,err=8
```

Comment: Use SimpleDateFormat's Format function.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve. What is your question?

Comment: The format string `dd-MM-yyyy` does not correspond to the format of the string that you are trying to parse, `2015-07-30`. Read the API documentation of [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), and use a matching format string.

Answer (score 0):

Your enddate is 2015-07-30. You need to use a matching format.

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```